# SQL Pick by Index When Using ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I want to pick say the 10th, 20th, and 50th entry in a dataset after it has been ordered by a column. What's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: Go with SQLite for the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that we have the following table:

```
create table Test
(
  value int
);
```

Here is a query that returns first, third and sixth row:

```
select value
from 
(
  select value, (select count(*) + 1 from Test t2 where t2.value < t1.value) as OrderId
  from Test t1
) tbl
where tbl.OrderId in (1,3,6)
```

You can try it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/36075/8). If there are duplicates in the *Test* table the solution above can return more than 3 rows.

**UPDATE**

If you want to sort by different column than `value` from my example you should modify the condition `t2.value < t1.value`. The general form is `t2.COLUMN_NAME < t1.COLUMN_NAME`.

Comment: I changed your table to contain `id, productname` in this [modified sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/46fa8/2). If i am not mistaken than the record `12, 'Bar 12'` is omitted which i would not expect.

Comment: Do you want a dataset to be ordered by the id or the product name column?

Comment: Are you asking me or OP? Based on my understanding of `after it has been ordered by a column` the question of OP includes the option to be ordered by any column.

Comment: If we sort by id column then the record `12, 'Bar 12'` will have OrderId = 7. If we sort by the product name column then the record `12, 'Bar 12'` will have OrderId = 3 (the same as the record `14, 'Bar 12'`). None of these cases fullfills `tbl.OrderId % 2 ==0` condition. Besides in your example you added `Order by productname` to the query but you didn't change the condition `t2.id < t1.id` to `t2.productname< t1.productname`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and most efficient way is to just use [LIMIT/OFFSET](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY whatever LIMIT 1 OFFSET 9
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY whatever LIMIT 1 OFFSET 19
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MyTable ORDER BY whatever LIMIT 1 OFFSET 49
```